# NestJS - TypeORM save() not updating document in the database

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm in the process of learning NestJS and TypeORM with a simple project where users can book offices. I have defined the office and bookings types and entities, and written a function that searches for an existing office and adds a booking subdocument to its bookings array. Save() returns the office document with the updated bookings field, but for some reason the database is not updated.

The office type looks like this:

```
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { BookingDto } from '../dto/booking.dto';

@ObjectType()
export class OfficeType {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;
  @Field()
  title: string;
  @Field()
  description: string;
  @Field(() => [BookingDto], { nullable: true })
  bookings: string[];
  @Field()
  price: number;
  @Field()
  owner: string;
}
```

The booking type inside the 'bookings' field:

```
import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { IsString, IsUUID } from 'class-validator';

@ObjectType()
export class BookingDto {
  @IsUUID()
  @Field()
  id: string;
  @IsUUID()
  @Field()
  officeId: string;
  @IsUUID()
  @Field()
  userId: string;
  @IsString()
  @Field()
  date_from: string;
  @IsString()
  @Field()
  date_until: string;
}
```

And the function for booking an office:

```
  async bookOffice(bookingInput: BookingInput): Promise<Office> {
    const { officeId, userId, date_from, date_until } = bookingInput;

    const booking = { id: uuid(), officeId, userId, date_from, date_until };

    const office = await this.officeRepository.findOne({
      id: officeId,
    });

    if (!office) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Office not found`);
    }

    office.bookings
      ? office.bookings.push(booking)
      : (office.bookings = [booking]);

    return await this.officeRepository.save(office);
  }
```

According to the TypeORM docs, save() can be used to update documents, so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save first the booking object and then save the office with the bookings.

```
booking = await this.bookingRepository.save(booking);

office.bookings ? office.bookings.push(booking) 
: (office.bookings =      [booking]);
this.officeRepository.save(office);
```

Comment: Hi tspentzas. I tried to put your example into practice but I'm running into a different issue.

I created a bookings module, with a resolver and a service and imported the module into app.module and office.module.
However, I'm not able to inject the booking repository into the office service. I get an error stating that Nest can't resolve the dependencies. 
What I did instead was injecting the booking service, calling the method for creating a booking. That part works and the booking is created in the bookings collection, but again the office object is not updated after using save().

Comment: I actually have more questions now. For example, it was my intention to just nest the bookings instead of having to create a module and a collection for them in the DB, is that not possible in NestJS/TypeORM?

Comment: @Dan-DH while looking for help on a similar topic, I noticed this comment. It is best on Stack Overflow to add a new question when it changes as your has.  If the answer above solved your previous ask, accept it so others can also see it worked. Then create a new question for the next ask you have, instead of the comments above. You can always embed links in the question to this question as well, but it is best to keep them as isolated asks.